Can Stallings' folding algorithm be used to find nontrivial relations among finitely many words in a free group (provided they exist)?
Stallings' folding algorithm allows us to take a finite set of words in the free group F_n, and find a free basis for the subgroup they generate. If the free basis has less words than the original set, then there exist nontrivial relations among our original set of words. My question is, can Stallings' folding algorithm be used to find (at least one) such relation? If not, is there a way to find such a relation other than brute force checking all countably many possibilities (at least we know if this will terminate eventually thanks to Stallings). I feel like the answer to the first question should be yes, but I haven't figured out a way to do it.
In particular, I'm interested in the F_2 case, but my guess is that it should be true for F_n.

Why the close votes?

Yes, this works. The input to Stallings fold algorithm is a map $f : R_m \to R_n$ where $R_m$ is a rose with one loop for each word in the given finite set, and $R_n$ is the rose with one loop per generator of $F_n$
Stallings fold algorithm factors the map $f$ into fold maps between graphs, that factorization having the form
$$f : R_m = G_0 \xrightarrow{f_1} G_1 \xrightarrow{f_2} \cdots \xrightarrow{f_K} G_K = R_n
$$
The individual folds $f_i : G_{i-1} \to G_i$ fall into two types.
The first type is a homotopy equivalence: two edge subpaths in $G_{i-1}$ with the same initial endpoint but otherwise disjoint are identified to each other by $f_i$. In this case $f_i$ gives an explicitly computable bijection between loops in $G_{i-1}$ and loops in $G_i$.
The second type of fold takes two whole edges of $G_{i-1}$ having the same initial endpoints and the same terminal endpoints, and folds them together to form a single edge of $G_i$. This map kills a specific loop in $G_{i-1}$, namely the one going forward along one of the two folded edges and then backwards along the other. The first time that happens, you can trace that loop from $G_{i-1}$ back to $G_0$ to get a relation which is killed. Although this kind of fold no longer induces a bijection of loops, it does induce a surjection, and moreover for each loop in $G_i$ you can explicitly compute a loop in $G_{i-1}$ which maps to the given loop.
So, as you go forward along the fold factorization, any time you do a new fold of the second type, obtaining a new loop which is killed, you can track that loop back alllll the way to $G_0$ to get a relation.
To summarize, look for all folds of the second type where you kill some loop, and trace each such loop all the way back to $G_0$ to get a relation. The collection of those relations normally generates the kernel of the original map $F_m \mapsto F_n$.

That makes sense, thank you!
